# Change the Docker context in Docker-Desktop

Tags: docker

I installed Docker-Desktop on Ubuntu 22.04.
Docker-Desktop use the desktop-linux context while I want to use the 'default' context.
Where is the configuration parameter to change the context used by Docker-Desktop ?
Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run command `docker context use default` in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted the matters in Docker forums and here is the [answer](https://forums.docker.com/t/is-this-possible-to-show-the-containers-running-in-default-context-in-a-docker-desktop-on-ubuntu/138239). The answer is : It is not possible. Do not try the `{ "default-context": "default" }` . It will freeze your docker desktop.

Answer (score 0):

- To change the context used by Docker-Desktop from 'desktop-linux' to
  'default', you can follow these steps:

  Open the Docker-Desktop settings by clicking on the Docker icon in
  the system tray and selecting "Settings".

  In the "General" tab, scroll down to the "Command Line" section and
  click on the "Advanced" button.

  In the "Docker Engine" section, add the following line to the text
  box:

  json Copy code {   "default-context": "default" } Click "Apply &
  Restart" to save the changes and restart Docker-Desktop.

  After restarting Docker-Desktop, it should now be using the 'default'
  context instead of 'desktop-linux'.

Comment: If I modify the configuration file like this :

`{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  }
}`

Docker-Desktop won't start anymore.

Comment: when I modified the configuration as described it failed to start.

Answer (score 0):

when using kubectl, enable this setting. then apply and restart

then `kubectl config use-context docker-desktop`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I able to use docker command with this in dekstop-linux context

```
apt install docker.io
```

after that just use

```
docker context use default
```